# Simulate mouse click automation on osk in c#

Tags: c#

This is my code for simulate mouse automation on an On-screen keyboard.

```cs
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    [DllImport("user32")]
    //[DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
    private static extern int apimouse_event(Int32 dwFlags, Int32 dX, Int32 dY, Int32 cButtons, Int32 dwExtraInfo);

    private const int MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN = 0x0002;
    private const int MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP = 0x0004;

    // For Win7 Home Edition 64 bit, to open OSK, go to Project -> Application Properties -> Compile ->
    // Target CPU -> set to x64 (in Visual Studio 2012)

    // Note app must be run with admin privileges to move window.

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    private static extern bool MoveWindow(IntPtr hWnd, int x, int y, int nWidth, int nHeight, bool bRepaint);

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    private static extern bool SetForegroundWindow(IntPtr hWnd);

    [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    private static extern bool GetWindowRect(IntPtr hWnd, out RECT lpRect);

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    private struct RECT
    {
        public int left;
        public int top;
        public int right;
        public int bottom;
    }

    private Process OSK;
    private Process ShutDownOSK;

    private Dictionary<string, Point> KeyboardKeys = new Dictionary<string, Point>();
    private Dictionary<string, Point> KeyboardNonKeys = new Dictionary<string, Point>();
    private List<string> TestStringList = new List<string>();

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        KeyboardKeys.Add("Escape", new Point(5, 34));
        KeyboardKeys.Add("`", new Point(11, 34));
        KeyboardKeys.Add("1", new Point(16, 34));
        KeyboardKeys.Add("2", new Point(21, 33));
        KeyboardKeys.Add("3", new Point(26, 33));
        KeyboardKeys.Add("4", new Point(31, 34));
        KeyboardKeys.Add("5", new Point(36, 33));
        KeyboardKeys.Add("6", new Point(41, 34));
        KeyboardKeys.Add("7", new Point(46, 33));
        KeyboardKeys.Add("8", new Point(51, 33));
        KeyboardKeys.Add("9", new Point(57, 34));
        KeyboardKeys.Add("0", new Point(62, 33));
        KeyboardKeys.Add("-", new Point(67, 33));
        KeyboardKeys.Add("=", new Point(72, 34));
        KeyboardKeys.Add("Back Space", new Point(78, 34));
        KeyboardKeys.Add("Home", new Point(86, 34));
        KeyboardKeys.Add("Page Up", new Point(94, 34));
        KeyboardKeys.Add("Tab", new Point(6, 47));
        KeyboardKeys.Add("q", new Point(14, 47));
        KeyboardKeys.Add("w", new Point(19, 48));
        KeyboardKeys.Add("e", new Point(24, 48));
        KeyboardKeys.Add("r", new Point(29, 48));
        KeyboardKeys.Add("t", new Point(34, 47));
        KeyboardKeys.Add("y", new Point(39, 47));
        KeyboardKeys.Add("u", new Point(44, 47));
        KeyboardKeys.Add("i", new Point(49, 48));
        KeyboardKeys.Add("o", new Point(54, 48));
        KeyboardKeys.Add("p", new Point(59, 48));
        KeyboardKeys.Add("[", new Point(64, 48));
        KeyboardKeys.Add("]", new Point(70, 49));
        KeyboardKeys.Add(@"\", new Point(74, 48));
        KeyboardKeys.Add("Delete", new Point(79, 48));
        KeyboardKeys.Add("End", new Point(86, 48));
        KeyboardKeys.Add("Page Down", new Point(94, 48));
        KeyboardKeys.Add("Caps Lock", new Point(7, 62));
        KeyboardKeys.Add("a", new Point(16, 61));
        KeyboardKeys.Add("s", new Point(21, 62));
        KeyboardKeys.Add("d", new Point(26, 62));
        KeyboardKeys.Add("f", new Point(31, 62));
        KeyboardKeys.Add("g", new Point(36, 62));
        KeyboardKeys.Add("h", new Point(42, 61));
        KeyboardKeys.Add("j", new Point(46, 61));
        KeyboardKeys.Add("k", new Point(52, 61));
        KeyboardKeys.Add("l", new Point(57, 61));
        KeyboardKeys.Add(";", new Point(62, 61));
        KeyboardKeys.Add("'", new Point(67, 61));
        KeyboardKeys.Add("Enter", new Point(75, 61));
        KeyboardKeys.Add("Insert", new Point(86, 61));
        KeyboardKeys.Add("Pause", new Point(95, 62));
        KeyboardKeys.Add("Shift", new Point(8, 75));
        KeyboardKeys.Add("z", new Point(19, 75));
        KeyboardKeys.Add("x", new Point(24, 75));
        KeyboardKeys.Add("c", new Point(29, 75));
        KeyboardKeys.Add("v", new Point(34, 75));
        KeyboardKeys.Add("b", new Point(39, 75));
        KeyboardKeys.Add("n", new Point(44, 75));
        KeyboardKeys.Add("m", new Point(49, 75));
        KeyboardKeys.Add(",", new Point(54, 75));
        KeyboardKeys.Add(".", new Point(59, 75));
        KeyboardKeys.Add("/", new Point(64, 75));
        KeyboardKeys.Add("Up Arrow", new Point(69, 75));
        KeyboardKeys.Add("Right Shift", new Point(77, 75));
        KeyboardKeys.Add("Print Screen", new Point(86, 75));
        KeyboardKeys.Add("ScrLk", new Point(95, 75));
        KeyboardKeys.Add("Control", new Point(5, 89));
        KeyboardKeys.Add("Windows", new Point(11, 89));
        KeyboardKeys.Add("Alternate", new Point(16, 90));
        KeyboardKeys.Add("Space", new Point(30, 89));
        KeyboardKeys.Add("Right Alternate", new Point(47, 90));
        KeyboardKeys.Add("Right Control", new Point(58, 88));
        KeyboardKeys.Add("Left Arrow", new Point(64, 88));
        KeyboardKeys.Add("Down Arrow", new Point(69, 89));
        KeyboardKeys.Add("Right Arrow", new Point(75, 89));
        KeyboardKeys.Add("Options", new Point(87, 89));
        KeyboardKeys.Add("Help", new Point(95, 88));
        KeyboardKeys.Add("Fn", new Point(79, 89));
        KeyboardKeys.Add("I have no idea", new Point(51, 90));
        KeyboardNonKeys.Add("Control Box Minimize", new Point(97, 9));
        KeyboardNonKeys.Add("X Close", new Point(31, 9));
        KeyboardNonKeys.Add("System Menu", new Point(15, 14));
        foreach (var Item in KeyboardKeys)
            ListBox1.Items.Add(Item.Key.ToString());
        foreach (var Item in KeyboardNonKeys)
            ListBox1.Items.Add(Item.Key.ToString());

        var CheckStatus = Process.GetProcessesByName("osk");
        if (CheckStatus.Length > 0)
            return;
        else
        {
            Process.Start("osk");
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
            var OEaCB = Process.GetProcessesByName("osk");
            OSK = OEaCB[0];
        }

        TestStringList.Add("Shift");
        TestStringList.Add("h");
        TestStringList.Add("e");
        TestStringList.Add("l");
        TestStringList.Add("l");
        TestStringList.Add("o");
        TestStringList.Add("Space");
        TestStringList.Add("Shift");
        TestStringList.Add("s");
        TestStringList.Add("k");
        TestStringList.Add("y");
        TestStringList.Add("p");
        TestStringList.Add("e");
        TestStringList.Add("Space");
        TestStringList.Add("Shift");
        TestStringList.Add("d");
        TestStringList.Add("u");
        TestStringList.Add("d");
        TestStringList.Add("e");
        TestStringList.Add(".");
        TestStringList.Add("Space");
        TestStringList.Add("Shift");
        TestStringList.Add("t");
        TestStringList.Add("h");
        TestStringList.Add("i");
        TestStringList.Add("s");
        TestStringList.Add("Space");
        TestStringList.Add("w");
        TestStringList.Add("a");
        TestStringList.Add("s");
        TestStringList.Add("Space");
        TestStringList.Add("a");
        TestStringList.Add("u");
        TestStringList.Add("t");
        TestStringList.Add("o");
        TestStringList.Add("t");
        TestStringList.Add("y");
        TestStringList.Add("p");
        TestStringList.Add("e");
        TestStringList.Add("d");
        TestStringList.Add("Space");
        TestStringList.Add("b");
        TestStringList.Add("y");
        TestStringList.Add("Space");
        TestStringList.Add("t");
        TestStringList.Add("h");
        TestStringList.Add("e");
        TestStringList.Add("Space");
        TestStringList.Add("t");
        TestStringList.Add("i");
        TestStringList.Add("m");
        TestStringList.Add("e");
        TestStringList.Add("r");
        TestStringList.Add(".");
        TestStringList.Add("Enter");
        TestStringList.Add("Enter");
        TestStringList.Add("Shift");
        TestStringList.Add("c");
        TestStringList.Add("Shift");
        TestStringList.Add("o");
        TestStringList.Add("Shift");
        TestStringList.Add("o");
        TestStringList.Add("Shift");
        TestStringList.Add("l");
        TestStringList.Add("Shift");
        TestStringList.Add("1");
        TestStringList.Add("Shift");
        TestStringList.Add("1");
        TestStringList.Add("Shift");
        TestStringList.Add("1");
        TestStringList.Add("Shift");
        TestStringList.Add("1");
        TestStringList.Add("Shift");
        TestStringList.Add("1");

        Timer1.Interval = 1000;
    }

    private void Form1_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
    {
        var CheckStatus = Process.GetProcessesByName("osk");
        if (CheckStatus.Length > 0)
        {
            ShutDownOSK = CheckStatus[0];
            ShutDownOSK.Kill();
        }
        else
            return;
    }

    private RECT rec;
    private Rectangle NewRect = new Rectangle();

    private void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        GetWindowRect(OSK.MainWindowHandle, out rec);
        NewRect.X = rec.left;
        NewRect.Y = rec.top;
        NewRect.Width = rec.right - rec.left + 1;
        NewRect.Height = rec.bottom - rec.top + 1;
        Label1.Text = "OSK width = " + NewRect.Width.ToString() + " .. OSK height = " + NewRect.Height.ToString();
    }

    private int Counter = 0;

    private void Timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Timer1.Interval = 50;

        Point ClickPoint = KeyboardKeys[TestStringList[Counter]];
        int PosX = System.Convert.ToInt32(NewRect.Left + ((NewRect.Right - NewRect.Left) / (double)100 * System.Convert.ToInt32(ClickPoint.X)));
        int PosY = System.Convert.ToInt32(NewRect.Top + ((NewRect.Bottom - NewRect.Top) / (double)100 * System.Convert.ToInt32(ClickPoint.Y)));

        Cursor.Position = new Point(PosX, PosY);
        RichTextBox1.Focus();

        apimouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN + MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP, PosX, PosY, 0, 0);

        Counter += 1;
        if (Counter == TestStringList.Count - 1)
        {
            Timer1.Stop();
            Counter = 0;
        }
    }

    private void ListBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (ListBox1.SelectedItem.ToString() != "Control Box Minimize" | ListBox1.SelectedItem.ToString() != "X Close" | ListBox1.SelectedItem.ToString() != "System Menu")
        {
            Point ClickPoint = KeyboardKeys[ListBox1.SelectedItem.ToString()];
            Text = ClickPoint.ToString();
            int PosX = System.Convert.ToInt32(NewRect.Left + ((NewRect.Right - NewRect.Left) / (double)100 * System.Convert.ToInt32(ClickPoint.X)));
            int PosY = System.Convert.ToInt32(NewRect.Top + ((NewRect.Bottom - NewRect.Top) / (double)100 * System.Convert.ToInt32(ClickPoint.Y)));

            Cursor.Position = new Point(PosX, PosY);

            RichTextBox1.Focus();

            apimouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN + MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP, PosX, PosY, 0, 0);
        }
    }

    private void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Timer1.Start();
    }
}
```

But I'm getting an error when I call it:

```
apimouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN + MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP, PosX, PosY, 0, 0);
```

Error:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.EntryPointNotFoundException'
> occurred in onkeyboard.exe
> Additional information: Unable to find an entry point named
> 'apimouse_event' in DLL 'user32'.

Comment: You don't need interop, window messages or executables to automate the UI in Windows. You can use the [Windows Accessibility and Automation APIs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winauto/microsoft-active-accessibility-and-ui-automation-compared). You'll find the equivalent .NET classes for Automation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.automation.automation?view=netcore-3.1). Windows has a full set of assistive technologies since [the 90s](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Active_Accessibility)

Comment: What are you trying to do? Test the on-screen keyboard? You can use Automation to enumerate its elements and activate them. You may want to look at [Respond to the presence of the touch keyboard](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/input/respond-to-the-presence-of-the-touch-keyboard) too.

Comment: The entrypoint name is "mouse_event".  Which has been obsolete for over two decades, you're supposed to use SendInput().  It doesn't make much sense to do this through OSK, SendInput() can also send keyboard input.  Like the equally obsolete keybd_event() used to do.

Answer (score 0):

The error looks like there is no `apimouse_event` function in the `user32` library. Make sure you written the correct name of both the library and the function.

Comment: I used the mouseclick code,    1) the mouseclick click point on the On-screen keyboard  but didn't get any On-screen keyboard  key value to the richtextbox   2)how to  click on osk key using the mouse automation